# Unable to login to MySQL with new user

Tags: mysql

I currently have a MySQL database which I have added a new user (abbvs) to identified by a password.

The users I have:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+-------+-----------+
| user  | host      |
+-------+-----------+
| abbvs | %         |
| stnd  | %         |
| stnd  | 127.0.0.1 |
| root  | 127.0.0.1 |
| root  | ::1       |
|       | ATTD      |
| root  | ATTD      |
|       | localhost |
| stnd  | localhost |
| root  | localhost |
+-------+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have added `SELECT` for all databases, and `ALL PRIVILEGES` to another followed by `flush_privileges;`

`SHOW GRANTS` gives me the following:

```
mysql> show grants for 'abbvs'@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for abbvs@%                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'abbvs'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '####' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `vardb`.* TO 'abbvs'@'%'                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I attempt to login via the CLI with the new user I get the following:

```
[root@ATTD ~]# mysql -u abbvs -p vardb
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abbvs'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is there anything that could be causing this? All other logins work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the system lacking a localhost user as well as a remote (any host) user.

Once the additional user had been added for localhost everything worked as expected.